# Entity Framework One to Many Recursive Relationship on self

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion

I'm stuck with a problematic, and not sure if this is the best way to solve it.

I've an Entity Category, which can have a list of sub categories ( child categories ) and has a Parent Category ( the only one without a parent category would be the "root" category. Is this the right way to do it ?

Category Class

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API ModelBuilder

```
//Category Parent - Child
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasOptional<Category>(category => category.ParentCategory)
        .WithMany(category => category.ChildCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(category => category.ParentId);
```

My seed method looks like this:

```
protected override void Seed(DAL.EF.MyDbContext context)
{
    var catParent = new Category() {Name = "ParentCat"};
    context.Categories.Add(catParent);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var catChild = new Category() { Name = "ChildCat", ParentId = catParent.Id};
    context.SaveChanges();

    catParent.ChildCategories.Add(catChild);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now the thing is, In the seed I add 2 categories, 1 parent 1 child. When I debug to check if the structure is good, it's actually correct. The only thing that really bugs me is this structure:

ParentCategory -> ChildCategory -> ParentCategory.

As it is recursive, the child object will have a object "ParentCategory", but I actually only need the ID of it, not the whole object.

Is this normal or is there a fix for it?

Comment: You've got the properties marked as virtual, so they're lazy loaded, so I wouldn't worry about the whole structure getting loaded into memory. But loading SQL object is fast, so I would be more inclined on just having the `ParentId` and creating the join table yourself.... just preference really

Comment: @CallumLinington how would I create the join table myself by entity framework ?

Comment: It is normal.

The moment you call .Add(catParent) the catParent object is added to the internal cache. Then it is attached automatically to the catChild object when you .Add(catChild).

What's your problem with it? It's not broken,

Comment: @makzr i know it's not broken, I don't know if it's the most efficient way of making this relationship work.

Comment: @TanguyB maybe you can share this question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see any problem with your relationship. There is no difference between `ParentCategory` navigation property and let say `Product.Category` property (if you put such).

Comment: The join table would just be an entity, `class ParentChildCategoryJoin { public int parentId {get;set;} public int childId {get;set;} }`